# What can mobs see through but can't shoot arrows through?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a mob farm.  In order to get the spiders to fall faster, I added Iron Golems behind fences.  Unfortunately, skeletons can shoot arrows through the fence.  What can I put between the Iron Golems and other mobs so that spiders can see the Iron Golems but skeletons can't shoot arrows through?

Comment: Have you tried with glass?

Answer (score 0):

Mobs can't see through glass apart from zombies and **spiders**. Therefore, skeletons won't be able to shoot through it but spiders will still see the iron golems. Just make a full glass wall separating your golems from the mob farm and the skeletons won't be a problem anymore.